# Convert PDF file to DOCX

Tags: r, pdf, docx

I am using

```
tools::texi2pdf(file=paste0("myfile.tex"), quiet=TRUE, clean=TRUE)
```

to produce pdf form latex. Now I am wondering if there is a **way in R** (tool or function etc.) to convert my pdf file to doc or docx?

I am aware of online converters but I need this in R code.

Comment: have you tried, e.g., [this](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/write-ms-word-document-using-r-with-as-little-overhead-as-possible/)

Comment: @MichaelChirico i did, but did not find anything usefull. I also looked at this [link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/exporting-r-output-to-ms-word-with-r2wd-an-example-session/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to convert pdf documents to docx with R with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_PDF_File <- "xxx.pdf"
path_To_Word_File <- "xxx.docx"

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_PDF_File),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
doc$SaveAs2(path_To_Word_File)
```

It turns out that we can open a PDF with Word in R and force a conversion to docx.